# HTML inside string to be taken as html and not displayed as string

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, string

I've tried h(), raw() and CGI, .html_safe classes with no result.

Example: lorem ipsum `<br/>` more text more text `<br/>` etc....

Comment: `h()` should do the job.

Comment: <%= h(mystring) %> does not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that html_safe did not work for you.

Something like

```
<%= myString.html_safe %>
```

where

```
myString = "lorem ipsum<br/>"
```

always works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you're looking for, [CGI::unescapeHTML](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escapeHTML)